# Fill control with another MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have experience in `C#`, but don't have any in `Javascript`.
What I want to achieve shouldn't be that hard, but I just can't get it to work:

I want to fill the text property of a label with the text property of a textbox.
This needs to be done at the `KeyUpEvent`.

I already created the `KeyUpEvent` and it is working, but it doesn't fill my label's text property using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.Quantity)").keyup(OnQuantityChanged);
    });

    function OnQuantityChanged()
    {
        alert("onQuantityChanged event fired.")
        document.getElementById('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)').value = document.getelementById('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)').value
    }
</script>
```

So I create a function called `OnQuantityChanged()` and I call this function on `KeyUp` event.
The alert in my function: `alert("onQuantityChanged event fired.")` gets called and shows me a dialog, so the function does get called.

I'm using `@Html.FieldIdFor`, for getting the id of the control. I think this is implemented by NopCommerce and down here is the definition of the `FieldIdFor` method:

```
public static string FieldIdFor<T, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
   var id = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
   // because "[" and "]" aren't replaced with "_" in GetFullHtmlFieldId
   return id.Replace('[', '_').Replace(']', '_');
}
```

I think I made a syntax error, but don't know how to debug Javascript, since setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio(2012), doesn't pause the code.

I think the line below has some incorrect syntax, correct me if i'm wrong:

```
document.getElementById('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)').value = document.getelementById('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)').value
```

**Update**

HTML of page is below:

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitPriceInclTax)@Model.UnitPriceInclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitPriceExclTax)@Model.UnitPriceExclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Quantity):
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { id = "lblQuantity"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubTotalInclTax)@Model.SubTotalInclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax):
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax)@Model.SubTotalExclTax
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to give your elements explicit IDs, and then use those in your jQuery selector?

Comment: Generally, break points aren't of much help with syntax errors.  And when asking about code that manipulates HTML, presenting the HTML helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need # when using document.getElementById just string representing id is enough.
2. There is no value of a label you could just set innerText property.

Pure javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById("YourID").innerText = "New Text";
```

JQuery Solution

```
$("#YourID").text("New Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

That part of server side code is not executed by ASP.NET since it is inside a string. You can resole using a variable to store the id:

```
var subTotalId = @Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.SubTotalExclTax);
```

and then use the subTotalId in your javascript (given that Html.FieldIdFor return the id of the element.

A better way is to use only javascript, with ASP.NET MVC you should know the ids of the DOM elements, so why do you need to find them at runtime?
Why not using Jquery:

```
$('#IdOfSubTotalElement').val();
```